# Getting Error in BaseAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have created a class that extends BaseAdapter.I don't have any custom.xml to inflate it .
Simple i have written this code

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();//Getting Error here to create a method getLayoutInflater
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        TextView title;
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        return (row);
    }
```

On getLayoutInflater() it is showing me the error to create a method.If i am creating this class in the main activity then it is working properly.So what i have to do remove this error

For **creating** the ListView i am calling the adapter as

```
myAdapter = new dataListAdapter(this,passengerList);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

For **Updation** of the ListView item i am calling the adapter as

```
 update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(isSuccess){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    passengerList[position] = newString;
                    listView.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(this,passengerList));
                }
            }
        });
```

MY BaseAdapter Class

```
class PassengerListView extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] Title;
    Activity activity;

    public dataListAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] text) {
        Title = text;
        activity = mainActivity;
    }

    public String[] getAllValues() {
        return Title;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();//Getting Error here to create a method getLayoutInflater
        View row = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        TextView title;
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        return (row);
    }
```

So on the updation code it showing me this error :

**The constructor PassengerListView(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String[]) is undefined**

Comment: show us `dataListAdapter`

Comment: you have two adapters `dataListAdapter` and `myAdapter`? Pls post the relevant adapter classes.

Comment: updated my code with base adapter

Comment: change this `listView.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(ActivityName.this,passengerList))`. you haven't read my previous comments

Comment: Also check the edited post now it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a method of activity class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater()

You need to pass the activity context to the constructor of asynctask and use the same

```
     new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this); // pass the activity context
```

Then in your adapter

```
     LayoutInflater mInflater; 
     Context mContext;
     public CustomAdapter(Context context)
     {
        // use the activity context now
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     }
```

In `getView

```
     row = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.customlayouttoinflate, parent, false);
```

Also you need to use a view holder.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

To update you need to update the list that populates your listview and call `notidyDataSetChanged` on your adapter.

Edit:

From my comments

You are doing `listView.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(this,passengerList))`in button click listener and you are using `this` instead of `ActivityName.this` .

Also i don't know why you have

```
 new dataListAdapter(this,passengerList);
```

Should be

```
 new PassengerListView (ActivityName.this,passengerList);
```

Change your constructor to

```
public PassengerListView(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] text) {
    Title = text;
    activity = mainActivity;
}
```

Comment: @Gaurav it takes long coz you haven't posted relevant codes. Next time remember to post the relevant codes or we will be only guessing and pls care to check the comments. the answer was already posted in the comments before if you realized and glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

`BaseAdapter` is not `Activity` therefore, it can NOT get the method of `Activity`, you need to pass the `Context`, in this case is your `Activity` to do so:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = your_activity.getLayoutInflater();//Getting Error here to create a method getLayoutInflater
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i am calling my class like this passengerList[position] = newString;
listView.setAdapter(new PassengerListView(passengerList));

Comment: @Gaurav why are you using` simple_list_item_1`. Should you not use custom layout instead if you need to customize your row?

Comment: @Gaurav then why do you need a custom adapter. A array adapter would be enough

Comment: @Gaurav single item in each row. would arrayadapter not be enough

Comment: that is not my problem .

Comment: my problem is that i am getting the error i am passing this is :The constructor PassengerListView(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String[]) is undefined

Comment: @Gaurav show us where you call the same. i guess you are doing it in button click listener and you are using this instead of ActivityName.this and also why do you need a custom adapter. also post the constructor of your adapter class

Comment: updated my question i need it for my future prospective so leave this question why BaseAdapter

Comment: @Gaurav you should post your adapter class also not enough info, pls post the relevant adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Raghunandan seems correct but only you don't need to inflate everytime. your code could be like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();//mContext being the private variable intialized by constructor.
    View row = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    }
    TextView title;
    title = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    title.setText(Title[position]);
    return (row);
}
```

Comment: my problem is when i calling for updation then i am getting the error  :The constructor PassengerListView(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String[]) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think it is useful for you....

```
     LayoutInflater mInflater;
     PassengerListView(Activity activity,String[] data)
     {
         this.activity=activity;
         this.data=data;
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
     }
```

Above is the constructor for your custom Adapter class that have two parameters which is change as per your requirements...

and below is the code for create a view and return it...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, false);
        }
        TextView title;
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        convertView.setTag(title);
        return convertView;
    }
```